# Delta functions in initial condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Here is a system of differential equations
$\newcommand{\diag}{\operatorname{diag}}$
$$
M^T \frac{\partial G(x,p,t)}{\partial t}
=\begin{aligned}[t]&(M^T-I)\diag(B_a^{-1}...B_{aN}^{-1})\diag(D_t^{1-a1}...D_t^{1-aN})G(x,p,t)
\\+&(M^T-I)\diag(K_{a1}...K_{aN})\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} \diag(D_t^{1-a1}...D_t^{1-aN})G(x,p,t)\end{aligned}
$$

Which contain three delta functions as initial condition.
$$G(x; A; t)=\delta(A)\delta(x)\delta(t)$$
where M is a transition matrix. B, K are constants.
I have no idea how to find two set initial conditions out of it.

Comment: I think that you need to give more context, like what system of differential equations you have.

Comment: @md2perpe if someone can help me how to use delta function as initial condition, that is enough

Comment: But that might depend on what the differential equations look like.

Comment: @md2perpei have updated the question please have a look.

Comment: On the right side, is the second derivative really for $t$ or should that have been for $x$?

Comment: @LutzLehmann sorry its for x. i have edited